# iPhone : How to validate email id when the user goes to the next textField and check if the email id is valid there only before he proceeds further

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have lots of textfields in one view and instead of user filling all the details and hit save button, I want to validate the email id entered there only. How to give the error message in the label when the user goes to the next textField

```
NSString *emailRegEx = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx];
if([emailTest evaluateWithObject:self.emailidTexField.text] == NO)
{
   // UILabel besides the text field and when the user goes to next field logic here.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
This may help... try this

-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if ([textField isEqual:emailidTexField])
     {
        NSString *emailRegEx = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
        NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx];
        if([emailTest evaluateWithObject:self.emailidTexField.text] == NO)
             {
               [emailidTexField becomeFirstResponder];
             }
      else{
               [Yournexttextfield becomeFirstResponder];
           } 
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use  this bellow  code..

Here when you click on return or Next key of keyBoard at that time this bellow `textFieldShouldReturn:`  `UITextField` delegate method called and you can write any validation or code with its condition bellow ...

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {

    if (textField==self.emailidTexField) {
        NSString *emailRegEx = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
        NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx];
        if([emailTest evaluateWithObject:self.emailidTexField.text] == NO)
        {
           // UILabel besides the text field and when the user goes to next field logic here.
           [self.emailidTexField resignFirstResponder];
           [YourNextTextFieldName becomeFirstResponder];
        }
        else{
           // Display message here that EmaiId is not valid
           return NO;
        }

    }
    return YES;
}
```

here i put the condition that if **textField** is **self.emailidTexField** then go inside and check validation if its true then it resign that textField keyboard and go cursor on NextTextField.

Comment: @DeepakThakur try this above code and let me know if you not get it.. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
      NSLog(@"%d",textFiled.tag);
      if(textField.tag==xxx){
    //check valid here
      }
      return YES;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add yourself as the delegate of the text field and perform your validation in `textFieldDidEndEditing:`. Be sure to call `endEditing:` on the view when the save button is pressed to ensure that the delegate method runs.

Answer (score 1):

```
 NSString *emailRegEx = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
 NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx];
 if([emailTest evaluateWithObject:self.emailidTexField.text] == NO)
 {
    [your next field becomesfirstresponder];
 }
```

Make your next textfield firstresponder to move the control to next field.

Answer (score 1):

Simple when the user goes to the next `UITextField` . Check in the

`- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField;`

whether it is the same `UITextField` or not , either you can set tags for the `UITextField's` to find out. Then just add a `UIAlertView` there like :-

```
 - (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
    {
          NSString *emailRegEx = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
          NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx];
          if([emailTest evaluateWithObject:self.emailidTexField.text] == NO)
          {
                UIAlertView *_alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Email is Invalid !!!  " delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil];
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set delegate of textfield and write following code in `UITextField` delegate method

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if ([textField isEqual:emailidTexField])
     {
        NSString *emailRegEx = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
        NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx];
        if([emailTest evaluateWithObject:self.emailidTexField.text] == NO)
             {
               [emailidTexField becomeFirstResponder];
             }
      else{
               [Yournexttextfield becomeFirstResponder];
           } 
      }
}
```